# Tangent space to representation variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory

In "Varieties of Representations of Finitely generated groups" by Lubotzky and Magid in page vi it claims that

"A. Weil showed that the tangent space to $R_n(T)$ at a representation $\rho$ is a subspace of $Z (T,Ad \circ \rho)$ (the space of one cocycles of T with coefficients in the representation)"

This proposition seems very important for the rest of the book but they provide no exact reference, for example to the paper where A. Weil proves this. Does anyone have a reference? Also, could anyone outline a concrete example about how do vectors of the tangent space correspond to 1-cocycles?

Comment: The reference to Weil is probably *Remarks on cohomology of groups*, Ann. of Math. 80(1) 149-157. But if you go a little further in the Lubotzky-Magid book, you'll find that the whole chapter 2 is devoted to this topic, with complete proofs and examples.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks a lot!